# Excel VBA - If value exists > x, add to sum, with a caveat

Tags: vba, excel

I was assisted last week with the below code to search a table for time values greater than 91 minutes, ignore the first instance, then sum subsequent instances in a running total.  I need to adjust the code so that if the first instance is greater than 95 minutes, ignore the "ignore the first instance" statement and sum that as well.

Current code is below:

```
Dim ttlBTimes As Variant
Dim ttlBThrshldTime As Double
Dim ttlBSumResults() As Double
Dim ttlBResultIndex As Long
Dim ttlBi As Long, ttlBj As Long
Dim ttlBFirst As Boolean

ttlBThrshldTime = TimeValue("01:31:00")
ttlBTimes = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F9").Value
ReDim ttlBSumResults(1 To UBound(ttlBTimes, 1) - LBound(ttlBTimes, 1) + 1, 1 To 1)
For ttlBi = LBound(ttlBTimes, 1) To UBound(ttlBTimes, 1)
    ttlBResultIndex = ttlBResultIndex + 1
    ttlBFirst = True
    For ttlBj = LBound(ttlBTimes, 2) To UBound(ttlBTimes, 2)
        If ttlBTimes(ttlBi, ttlBj) > ttlBThrshldTime Then
            If ttlBFirst Then
                ttlBFirst = False
            Else
                ttlBSumResults(ttlBResultIndex, 1) = ttlBSumResults(ttlBResultIndex, 1) + ttlBTimes(ttlBi, ttlBj) - ttlBThrshldTime
            End If
        End If
    Next ttlBj
Next ttlBi
ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Resize(UBound(ttlBSumResults, 1)).Value = ttlBSumResults
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using formula?

Comment: What do you mean?  I am using the VBA script above, I just need a slight edit.

Comment: something like this `=SUMIF($A$1:$A$11,">=50",$B$1:$B$11)-INDEX($B$1:$B$11,MATCH(50,$A$1:$A$11,0))`  this looks for 50 or over, ignoring the 1st instance, which you can tweak.

Comment: Sorry @Nathan_Sav I need this in VBA form.

Comment: so use `worksheetfunction`  sometimes we can over-engineer using excel's code nicely done for us.  or even `ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Resize(<<X>>).formula= "=SUMIF($A$1:$A$11,">=50",$B$1:$B$11)-INDEX($B$1:$B$11,MATCH(‌​50,$A$1:$A$11,0))" `  where the `WORKSHEETFUNCTION.COUNTIF` would assist you in deriving X, potentially 1 or 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

try this, 95 is 01:35

```
Dim ttlBTimes As Variant
Dim ttlBThrshldTime As Double
Dim ttlBSumResults() As Double
Dim ttlBResultIndex As Long
Dim ttlBi As Long, ttlBj As Long
Dim ttlBFirst As Boolean

ttlBThrshldTime = TimeValue("01:35:00")
ttlBTimes = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F9").Value
ReDim ttlBSumResults(1 To UBound(ttlBTimes, 1) - LBound(ttlBTimes, 1) + 1, 1 To 1)
For ttlBi = LBound(ttlBTimes, 1) To UBound(ttlBTimes, 1)
    ttlBResultIndex = ttlBResultIndex + 1
    For ttlBj = LBound(ttlBTimes, 2) To UBound(ttlBTimes, 2)
        If ttlBTimes(ttlBi, ttlBj) > ttlBThrshldTime Then
                ttlBSumResults(ttlBResultIndex, 1) = ttlBSumResults(ttlBResultIndex, 1) + ttlBTimes(ttlBi, ttlBj) - ttlBThrshldTime
        End If
    Next ttlBj
Next ttlBi
ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Resize(UBound(ttlBSumResults, 1)).Value = ttlBSumResults
excel vba excel-vba
```

Comment: am I correct however that this would then effectively get rid of the 91 to 95 minute range?  I need the code to still count instance in that range (throwing out the first instance, and counting subsequent)

Comment: you have asked to ignore "the ignore.." that what the code does. If you want to reactivate "the ignore..." just go back to the initial code and replace 01:31 by 01:35

Comment: Correct; ignore "the ignore" if the value exceeds 01:35.  Otherwise, process "the ignore".  I am trying to understand your code, so if it already does that, my apologies.